# android SIM Card change notifier

Tags: android, google-play

i am developing an android app. what i am doing is i have added a feature which detects the sim number. if the user changed the sim number, i get the current sim number and then i am emailing the new number to the user. so how am i detecting this is i am automatically sending a message from an app  to my server and then i detect the number. so now the problem is when i  put the app on the Google play store .. they are deleting my app and what reason they are giving me is "you cant send an sms from the phone without user permission which is against their policies.so i am wondering why then other apps are working and doing the same thing .. for example this app

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=instigate.simCardChangeNotifier&hl=en

there are many apps on the google play store which detecting the number and i think they are pretty much using the same technique to get the current number.. so i want to know what exactly they are doing or how they are playing tricks with Google so Google cant detect them

Comment: Maybe they are saying to set permission in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @SantoshKumar well what kind of permission.. well if there is a chance that somehow i miss the adding permission then why i am sending successfully number to my user..and then google detects it and then they delete my app after one or two days..

Comment: Why not contact [Google Play developer support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/2857301)?

Comment: i have contacted them..they are saying that "it is violation of our article number 3 or bla bla and now we are not going to contact you again on this matter" etc ...